# Can't get the response I want from Wordpress JWT Auth using React (Native). It works fine using Postman

Tags: javascript, wordpress, react-native, jwt

I have an old Wordpress site. I installed the plugin [JWT Auth](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-auth/) so my React Native app can authenticate users from this website.

I have this React code:

```
function LoginScreen({navigation}) {
    const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('')
    const apiurl = 'https://wordpresswebsite.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/'

    function submitLogin() {
                    
        axios.post(apiurl, {
            body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password })
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        })

    }
}
```

The response I get is `code: "jwt_auth_no_auth_header"`

However, when I use **Postman**, I get the expected `"code":"jwt_auth_valid_credential"` without any problems.

What is going on here and how can I get the result like in Postman?

Comment: Have you configured your axios instance to include the JWT in its headers? From your code sample it doesn't look like you're including the header at all.